# How to set read permissions for all authenticated users without language dependency?

Tags: permissions

I would like to set the read permissions to all authenticated users on a site collection.

First I was using this code below, but I got an exception that this permission level is not existed.

```
roleAssignment.RoleDefinitionBindings.Add(web.RoleDefinitions["Read"]);
```

When I translate the permission level "Read" to dutch "Lezen" it works (see code below). But I do not would like to hardcode some language. Is it possible to set permissions without using explicit the language of the site?

```
roleAssignment.RoleDefinitionBindings.Add(web.RoleDefinitions["Lezen"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using SPRoleType

I hope this helps, I haven't tried it out, but here is an example :

The way that would cause localisation issues :

```
web.RoleDefinitions["Read"];
```

The way that wouldn't cause localisation issues :

```
web.RoleDefinitions.GetByType(SPRoleType.Reader);
```

Taken from here :

http://blog.myitechnology.com/2010/04/sharepoint-tips-working-in-localized.html

It's a good read :)

Here is a full list of roles :

https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/microsoft.sharepoint.sproletype.aspx

And some help with dealing with it programatically

https://tjendarta.wordpress.com/tag/sproletype/

Kind regards,